# Apache flink vs Apache Beam (With flink runner)

Tags: apache-flink, apache-beam, stream-processing

I am considering using Flink or Apache Beam (with the flink runner) for different stream processing applications. I am trying to compare the two options and make the better choice. Here are the criteria I am looking into and for which I am struggling to find info for the flink runner (I found basically all the info for flink standalone already) :

- Ease of use
- Scalability
- Latency
- Throughput
- Versatility
- Metrics generation
- Can deploy with Kubernetes (easily)

Here are the other criteria which I think I already know the answers too:

- Ability to do stateful operations: Yes for both
- Exactly-once guarantees: Yes for both
- Integrates well with Kafka: Yes for both (might be a little harder with beam)
- Language supported:

  - Flink: Java, Scala, Python, SQL
  - Beam: Java, Python, GO

If you have any insight on these criteria for the flink runner please let me know! I will update the post if I find answers!

Update: Good article I found on the advantage of using Beam (don't look at the airflow part):
https://www.astronomer.io/blog/airflow-vs-apache-beam/

Comment: Ease/Versatility are very opinionated. AFAIK, Beam operations get translated into the respective runners, therefore there is some performance penalty when using it, and also might not have direct access to the runner's metrics

Comment: Regarding your update, unclear why you've introduced Airflow into the question. It's not the same thing

Comment: The airflow part is irrelevant should have mentionned

Answer (score 2):

Similar to OneCricketeer's comment, it's quite subjective to compare these 2.

If you are absolutely sure that you are going to use FlinkRunner, you could just cut the middle man and directly use Flink. And it saves you trouble in case Beam is not compatible with a specific FlinkRunner version you want to use in the future (or if there is a bug). And if you are sure all the I/Os you are going to use are well supported by Flink and you know where/how to set up your FlinkRunner (in different modes), it makes sense to just use Flink.

If you consider moving to other languages/runners in the future, Beam offers language and runner portabilities for you to write a pipeline once and run everywhere.

Beam supports more than Java, Python and Go:

- JavaScript: https://github.com/robertwb/beam-javascript
- Scala: https://github.com/spotify/scio
- Euphoria API
- SQL

Runners:

- DataflowRunner
- FlinkRunner
- NemoRunner
- SparkRunner
- SamzaRunner
- Twister2Runner

Details can be found on https://beam.apache.org/roadmap/.

Comment: Thanks for the input! The final decision will definitely be subjective, but I want to base myself on somewhat objective criteria. The runners and the added language flexibility might be nice in the future. I didn't find any appealing reason to go for one or the other for the moment.

Comment: @GuillaumeDelmas-Frenette Sounds like you're experiencing ["Speculative Generality"](https://code-smells.com/dispensables/speculative-generality) before you even write the code

Answer (score 1):

Answering from a [blog](https://flink.apache.org/2020/02/22/apache-beam-how-beam-runs-on-top-of-flink/) in the Flink website, this can be helpful

> **Reasons to use Beam with Flink # Why would you want to use Beam with
> Flink instead of directly using Flink?**

> Ultimately, Beam and Flink
> complement each other and provide additional value to the user. The
> main reasons for using Beam with Flink are the following:
>
> - Beam provides a unified API for both batch and streaming scenarios.
> - Beam comes with native support for different programming languages,
>   like Python or Go with all their libraries like Numpy, Pandas,
>   Tensorflow, or TFX.
> - You get the power of Apache Flink like its
>   exactly-once semantics, strong memory management and robustness.
> - Beam
>   programs run on your existing Flink infrastructure or infrastructure
>   for other supported Runners, like Spark or Google Cloud Dataflow.
> - You
>   get additional features like side inputs and cross-language pipelines
>   that are not supported natively in Flink but only supported when using
>   Beam with Flink.